# Por que quando eu carrego meu layout blade, meu css não aparece?

Tags: php, css, laravel, layout

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código definindo o layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>VPO - @yield('title')</title>
    <!-- Icons -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../../../public/css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../../../public/css/style.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../../../public/css/font-awesome.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

</head>

<body id="layout">
@section('sidebar')
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="row">

                <ul class="side-nav fixed hoverable indigo darken-3">
                    <li class="indigo darken-4 z-depth-2">
                        <div class="row">
                            <br>
                            <div class="col s4 m4 l4">
                                <img src="../../../public/images/989.jpg" alt="" class="circle responsive-img">
                            </div>
                            <center>
                                <div class="col s12 m8 l8">

                                    <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
                                    <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="material-icons indigo-text text-darken-4">face</i> Perfil</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="material-icons indigo-text text-darken-4">keyboard_tab</i> Sair</a>
                                        </li>

                                    </ul>
                                    <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
                                    <a class='dropdown-button btn red col s12' href='#' data-activates='dropdown1'>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspRafael<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a>

                                    <p class="white-text">Professor</p>
                                </div>
                            </center>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col s12">
                            <form>
                                <center>
                                    <h4 class="white-text">Nova Prova</h4>
                                </center>
                                <p class="white-text">Data:<input type="date"></p>
                                <div class="input-field white-text">
                                    <input id="" type="text">
                                    <label for="">Título</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-field white-text">
                                    <input id="" type="text">
                                    <label for="">Sala</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-field white-text">
                                    <input id="" type="text">
                                    <label for="">Diciplina</label>
                                </div>

                                <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn red">Enviar</a>
                            </form><br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col s12 z-depth-5">
                            <form>
                                <center>
                                    <h4 class="white-text">Contato</h4>
                                </center>
                                <p class="white-text"><i class="material-icons red-text">call</i> (19) 3862-0888 / (19) 3862-0177 </p>
                                <p class="white-text"><i class="material-icons red-text">email</i> Mail@example.com </p>
                                <p class="white-text"><i class="material-icons red-text">home</i> Rua. Ariovaldo Silveira Franco, 237 </p>
                            </form>
                        </div>
            </div>
<div class="col s3"></div>

             @show
             <div class="col s9">
            @yield('content')
            </div>
</body>

<!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../js/app.js"></script>

<!-- efeito do botão -->
<script>
    $('.fixed-action-btn').openFAB();
    $('.fixed-action-btn').closeFAB();
    $('.fixed-action-btn.toolbar').openToolbar();
    $('.fixed-action-btn.toolbar').closeToolbar();

</script>
<!-- fim efeito botão -->

<script>
    $('.dropdown-button').dropdown('open');
    $('.dropdown-button').dropdown('close');

</script>
<!-- select -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('select').material_select();
    });

</script>
<!-- fim do select -->

<!-- data -->
<script>
    $('.datepicker').pickadate({
        selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
        selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year,
        today: 'Today',
        clear: 'Clear',
        close: 'Ok',
        closeOnSelect: false // Close upon selecting a date,
    });

</script>
<!-- fim data-->


</html>
```

Meu código com o layout:

```
@extends('layouts.layoutprofessor')

@section('title', 'Professor')

@section('sidebar')
    @parent


@endsection

@section('content')
<table class="striped bordered ">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Código</th>
                <th>Data</th>
                <th>Situação</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr class="cyan lighten-5">
                <td>001</td>
                <td>18/06/2017</td>
                <td>Encerrada</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>002</td>
                <td>18/05/2017</td>
                <td>Aberta &nbsp<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-floating indigo modal-trigger" href=""><i class="large material-icons">remove_red_eye</i></a>
                    &nbsp<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-floating red modal-trigger" href="#modal1"><i class="large material-icons">clear</i></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="cyan lighten-5">
                <td>003</td>
                <td>27/05/2017</td>
                <td>Aberta &nbsp<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-floating indigo modal-trigger" href=""><i class="large material-icons">remove_red_eye</i></a>
                    &nbsp<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-floating red modal-trigger" href="#modal1"><i class="large material-icons">clear</i></a></a></td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>



@endsection
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Sou meio novo com isso. Obrigado pela atenção!

Edit: 
Os erros que estão aparecendo no console do navegador 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Veja o console do navegador, deve ter algum erro como 404, 403 ou 500, copia os erros e coloca na pergunta por favor.

Comment: Já tentou utilizar a URL absoluta dos arquivos CSS e imagens?

Comment: Tente utilizar a chamada do CSS no arquivo que define o Layout desta forma: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/sweetalert.css') }}">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apague os pontos href="../../..

O laravel le a public como raiz